# Next and previous button from android sqllitedatabase

Tags: android, sqlite

What am I missing in this code? It shows me only the first record from the database and does not move to the next record.

#### Next button:

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.btnNext) {

     try {
            pos++;
            database.Open();
            Houes h = new Houes();
            database.Shows(h, pos);
            txNo.setText("" + h.getHouse_id());
            txAdd.setText("" + h.getHouse_address());
            txOn.setText("" + h.getHouse_owner());
            txVal.setText("" + h.getHouse_value());
            txDis.setText("" + h.getHouse_discount());
            database.Close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

#### database class:

```
protected void Shows(Houes house , int p ) {


   // String[] columns = {house_id, house_address, house_owner, house_value, house_discount};
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from " + database_table, null);


    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(house_id);
    int iAdd = c.getColumnIndex(house_address);
    int iOwn = c.getColumnIndex(house_owner);
    int iVal = c.getColumnIndex(house_value);
    int iDis = c.getColumnIndex(house_discount);

    if(p==1){
        c.moveToFirst();
    }else if(p>1&&c.isAfterLast()==false){
        c.moveToNext();
    }


house.setHouse_id(c.getInt(iRow));
house.setHouse_address(c.getString(iAdd));
house.setHouse_owner(c.getString(iOwn));
house.setHouse_value(c.getInt(iVal));
house.setHouse_discount(c.getInt(iDis));




    }
```

Comment: simple way would be , fetch all records (which you are doing currently) and store them in arraylist of POJO type and then simply show records according to index

Comment: How I can move to next and prevoius in arraylist

Comment: using `pos` if next then `list.get(++pos)` and if prev `list.get(--pos)` and make sure to check the size while moving next and previous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change **Shows** to return the cursor that it extracts an do nothing else e.g.

```
Cursor Shows() {

    return Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from " + database_table, null);
}
```

call the **shows** method before and outside of the next button click listener and also display the first house values after something along the lines of :-

```
cursor = db.shows();
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(house_id); //etc
} else {
  //handle no houses to show
}

......
```

within your next button listener

```
    if (cursor.moveToNext)  {
        //do you stuff here
    } else {
        //handle end of rows here
    }
```

previous button listener basically the same but uses `moveToPrevious`.

if you need to position to a specific house then loop through the cursor after it has been returned i.e. just move the existing code from **Shows**.

Make sure to do `cursor.close();` when you have finished accessing the cursor.